# Keep getting Invalid Hook call error on my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, smartcontracts

I'm trying to get some information from my smart contract to display on my React app front page. However, anytime I try to do so I get this error

```
Server Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
resolveDispatcher
file:///Users/louiefranchino/Documents/eventsystem/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1476:13)
useContext
file:///Users/louiefranchino/Documents/eventsystem/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1484:20)
Html
../../node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js (9:873)
processChild
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3353:14)
resolve
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3270:5)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.render
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3753:22)
ReactDOMServerRenderer.read
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (3690:29)
renderToStaticMarkup
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js (4314:27)
renderDocument
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js (2:749)
renderToHTML
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js (54:698)
runMicrotasks
<anonymous>
processTicksAndRejections
internal/process/task_queues.js (94:5)
async
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js (112:97)
async
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js (105:142)
async DevServer.renderToHTMLWithComponents
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js (137:387)
async DevServer.renderToHTML
file:///Users/louiefranchino/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js (138:610)
```

This is strange as my code previously worked, however now I get nothing but this error. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
import factory from "../ethereum/factory";

class EventIndex extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    const events = await factory.methods.getDeployedEvents().call();

    return { events };
  }


  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.events[0]}</div>;
  }
}

export default EventIndex;
```

If anyone could help me please let me know.

EDIT: Update: I think there is an error with my dependencies or something. When I try to run my previous applications which worked fine. I'm also getting errors on that albeit different errors. I read that this Hook error can display if you have two react packages, how could I go about resolving this?

Here is the full code:
https://github.com/Loustaaa/eventsystem/tree/test

Comment: The error message is very descriptive. It states that you are mixing (calling) hooks inside of a class component method. And since you aren't posting the whole code, I believe it is inside the ```getDeployedEvents``` function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this. My getDeployedEvents function is really simple so I doubt it's that.     function getDeployedEvents() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedEvents;
    }

Comment: From your stack track, it looks like `node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js` (line 9) is calling `useContext` (a hook method). You should look at that file, see what function it is, and see where you're calling it.

Comment: @edemaine I can't seem to find the next folder in my node_modules. I don't think it's there

Comment: The full path quoted is `../../node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js` so maybe go up two (or one or more) directories and look at the `node_modules` there?

Comment: @edemaine I went into my directory via terminal and looked in node_modules for the next directory and it doesn't exist

Comment: @edemaine Here's all my code, could you please take a look https://github.com/Loustaaa/eventsystem/tree/test